# display div next to label without breaking line

Tags: html, css

I would like to drow a label and input text next to it.
the input text must be inside a div - later I would like to add element to the div.
I am using float in order to display the div next to the label/

here is me html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//Dtd XHTML 1.0 transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/tr/xhtml1/Dtd/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        label: <div style="float:left;"><input type="text" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ihe problem is that I get the div before the text.

http://jsfiddle.net/2wNbR/

How can I fix it?

**UPDATE**
I actually want to use an autocomplete plugin I've wrote instead of the input text. The autocomplete uses a div. I don't want to create a "prerequisite" to the label so solution like add `<span style="float:right"></span>` around the label are not good.

**UPDATE2**
I thought it is not necessary but I see it is importent.
Here is the full example: http://jsfiddle.net/2wNbR/16/

```
.Autocomplete {
    direction: ltr;
}

.Autocomplete, .Autocomplete .Arrow, .Autocomplete .CodeField,
.Autocomplete .SmartField, .Autocomplete .Selector {
    float:left;
}

.Autocomplete .Arrow {
    background-image:url(drop.gif);
    background-position:top right;
    height:17px;
    width:17px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.Autocomplete .OptionsListHolder {
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
}

.Autocomplete .OptionsList
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:999;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial (Hebrew);
}

.Autocomplete .CodeField
{
    width:40px;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    height:13px;
}

.Autocomplete .SmartField
{
    width:auto;
    border: 1px solid #888888;
    height:13px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial (Hebrew);
}

    Customer:
    <div class="Autocomplete">
        <input type="text" class="CodeField" />
        <div class="Selector">
            <input type="text" class="SmartField" />
            <div class="Arrow"></div>
            <div class="OptionsListHolder">
                <select class="OptionsList" size="8">
                    <option>opt 1</option>
                    <option>opt 2</option>
                    <option>opt 3</option>
                    <option>opt 4</option>
                    <option>opt 5 - long item text</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>
    <br>
    text to check if the OptionsList is override this text
```

Comment: there is no label tag in your latest fiddle. be specific what u want

Comment: @diEcho: I haven't mentioned there is a label tag. I wrote there is a label.

Comment: @Naor: Can't quite see what you are trying to achieve there, it's a bit of a mess.

Comment: @Orbling: I want the Customer label to be in the same line as the autocomplete structure. Go in the JSFiddle and you'll see. What is mess?

Comment: @Orbling: What is wrong with it? it is ok. This is the address: http://jsfiddle.net/2wNbR/16/ and you also have code in the question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
<div style="display:inline-block;"><input type="text" /></div>
```

And you also might want to check the `<label>` html element.

Answer (score 2):

Just put a `<span>` around the label and float that too, remember to clear it.

```
<span style="float: left;">label: </span><div style="float:left;"><input type="text" /></div>
```

Comment: NB. Not entirely sure why you need the `<div>` around the `<input>` in this case, I assume this is a cut back example.

Answer (score 0):

```
label: <span><input type="text" /></span>
```

or

```
<div style="float:left">label:</div><div><input type="text" /></div>
```

will help but if you can say the purpose you will more likely get an appropriate answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the poster is actually using coldfusion and using `<cfinput>` rather than `<input>` -- if this is the case, here's the scenario:

You have a `<cfinput>` tag with an autosuggest= value and you want to put a text label to the left of the input field.

`<cfinput` with autosuggest uses ajax and automatically adds styled ajax divs to, including the `cf.css` which adds the `float:left;` style.

One way you can work around this is by surrounding your label and the cfinput in a table, with each in their own `<td>`'s..

so `<table border=0><tr><td>label:</td><td><cfinput autosuggest="value1,value2,etc" name="inputname"></td></tr></table>`

That should do it!